# Why my pointer code is giving me wrong output in C?

Tags: c, pointers

Why my pointer code is giving me wrong output ?.

Where, my actual **code** is :

```
 void fun1(int *x, int *y){
    *x = 50;
    *y = 100;
    fun2(&x, &y);
    printf("%d %d ", x, y);
}

void fun2(int *x, int *y){
    *x = 6;
    *y = 7;
}

void main()
{
    int x = 5;
    int y = 10;
    fun1(&x, &y);
    printf("%d %d",x,y);
}
```

My expected output is like this : 6 7 6 7

It's giving me output like this : 6 7 50 100

Thanks.

Comment: You're lucky this works at all.  Start by using function prototypes, or at least declaring `fun2` before `fun1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `fun1` the expression `&x` is a pointer *to the pointer*. It's of type `int **`.

You should not use the address-of operator there, since `x` and `y` already are pointers.

An easy way to get the compiler to warn you about this is to declare thje function `fun2` before you use it:

```
// Declare fun2 prototype
void fun2(int *x, int *y);

void fun1(int *x, int *y)
{
    ...
}

// Define fun2 implementation
void fun2(int *x, int *y)
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Before use `void fun2(int*, int*)`, you must declare or define it
2. In funxtion `fun1`, the line `printf("%d %d ", x, y);` should be `printf("%d %d ", *x, *y);`, for `x` and `y` are `int*`
3. In function `fun1`, the line `fun2(&x, &y);` should be `fun2(x, y);` for `x` and `y` are `int*`

The following `code` could work:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void fun2(int *x, int *y){
    *x = 6;
    *y = 7;
}

void fun1(int *x, int *y){
    *x = 50;
    *y = 100;
    fun2(x, y);
    printf("%d %d\n", *x, *y);
}

int main()
{
    int x = 5;
    int y = 10;
    fun1(&x, &y);
    printf("%d %d\n",x,y);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Method 1. Point To Point To Int 

void fun1(int *x, int *y){
    *x = 50;
    *y = 100;
    fun2(&x, &y);
    printf("%d %d ", *x, *y);
}

void fun2(int **x, int **y){
    **x = 6;
    **y = 7;
}

void main()
{
    int x = 5;
    int y = 10;
    fun1(&x, &y);
    printf("%d %d",x,y);
}
```